# Check for debugger statement with husky pre-commit

Tags: eslint, lint, tslint, pre-commit, husky

I am curios about how to check if the staged files contain `debugger` statement or not? if yes, throw error and prevent to commit. Could someone help me with a clue how to do that?

Tnx